# How does the cache synchronization protocol work in Apache Ignite?

Tags: database, caching, ignite, in-memory-database

When we use Apache Ignite in **In-Memory** mode <sup>[1]</sup> and all the data is replicated to every node in the cluster (`cacheMode` is set as `REPLICATED` <sup>[2]</sup>), how does the cache synchronization protocol work?

*NOTE: The question is not about the cache synchronization between the primary and the backup(s). <sup>[3]</sup>*

```xml
<property name="cacheConfiguration">
  <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
    <!-- some other properties -->
    <property name="cacheMode" value="REPLICATED"/>
  </bean>
</property>
```

[1] https://ignite.apache.org/arch/multi-tier-storage.html
[2] https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/data-modeling/data-partitioning#replicated
[3] https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/configuring-caches/configuring-backups

Comment: The same as a partitioned cache. A replicated cache is (basically) a partitioned cache configured to have "unlimited" backups.

Comment: Thanks @StephenDarlington! So, just to clarify more, the affinity function determines the mapping between keys and partitions. Then, there is another protocol to distribute that partitions to all the nodes (when the cache is configured as `REPLICATED`). Right? So, may I know, what's that protocol and any source of information for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s only one algorithm: the rendezvous hashing algorithm. It’s used for both partitioned and replicated caches. First it’s used to map the key to the partition. Then the same algorithm is used to map partitions to nodes. More in [this blog](https://www.gridgain.com/resources/blog/data-distribution-in-apache-ignite).